# finding out specific words using kafka stream

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have created rest end point from there data is coming and I am sending it to kafka topic "topic-feedback" . Now I want to process that data and send it to another kafka topic "topic-goodWord". Now from rest end point data is coming to topic "topic-feedback" correctly but after processing it and sending it to another topic "topic-goodWord" , data is not seeing in "topic-goodWord".

There is no error in program

Here is my code:

```
@Configuration
public class FeedbackStream {
    
    Set<String> GOOD_WORDS = Set.of("happy", "good", "helpful");

    @Bean
    public KStream<String,String> KStreamFeedback(StreamsBuilder builder)
    {
        var stringSerde = Serdes.String();
        var feedbackSerde = new JsonSerde<>(Feedback.class);

        ((JsonDeserializer) feedbackSerde.deserializer()).setUseTypeHeaders(false);
        
         var sourceStream = builder.stream("topic-feedback", Consumed.with(stringSerde,feedbackSerde))
                                                        .flatMapValues(mapperGoodWords());
          
        sourceStream.to("topic-goodWord", Produced.with(stringSerde,stringSerde));

        return sourceStream;
    }





private ValueMapper<Feedback,Iterable<String> > mapperGoodWords() 
    {
        return feedback -> Arrays
                           .asList(feedback.getFeedback().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").toLowerCase()
                           .split("\\s+")).stream()
                           .filter(word -> GOOD_WORDS.contains(word)).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Feedback.java

```
public class Feedback {
    
    private String location;
    private int rating;
    private String feedback;     
    
    // getters,setters
}
```

kafka stream Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class KafkaStreamConfig {
    
    @Bean(name = KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_CONFIG_BEAN_NAME)
    public KafkaStreamsConfiguration kafkaStreamConfig()
    {
        var props = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "kafka-stream");
      
         props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:9092");

        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG,Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.USE_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS,"false");
      
        return new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(props);
    }
}
```

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: You've created a KStream topology, but where do you actually start it so that any data gets read/processed?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have created rest end point from there data is coming and I am sending it to kafka topic "topic-feedback" . Now I want to process that data and send it to another kafka topic "topic-goodWord".  Now from rest end point data is coming to topic "topic-feedback" correctly  but after processing it and sending it to another topic "topic-goodWord" , data is not seeing in "topic-goodWord".  And there is no error in the program.

Comment: I understand what your code is trying to do, but it's not clear if you have called `start()` like the answer shows. All you've done here is defined some methods and a bean. Maybe there's no error because you never load this bean anywhere to start the stream

Comment: @ OneCricketeer In my previous practice program on kafka topic I had not used `start()` but they worked fine. Now I created new topic but seems that I did not mention about new   stream in config. Is this the issue ?  I am confused. Please help me.

Comment: I don't know what Spring library you're ultimately using here, but it's not the Kafka Streams Binder, based on the documentation https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/3.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_kafka_streams_binder

Answer (score 0):

Tushar, thats what the problem i see with kafka streams, sometimes, it eats those exceptions. but anyway, now your problem, if its not reaching other topic means itcould be serialization issue. also are you doing this as i do not see here.

```
var kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(sourceStream,  streamsConfiguration);
kafkaStreams.start();
```

Comment: I have added kafka stream config. Apart from this I have files which works for another topic. This time I have created new topic. But I have not configured the new stream( channel ) of the new topic. Is this the issue ? because this is the 1st program of new topic and new stream which is not showing output.  And sorry, but I have not used your above code in my previous program also but they work fine. Please guide me, I am confused.